# Is there a shorthand for Ruby Blocks?

Tags: ruby, verbosity

I find myself annoyed with the following verbose writing in Ruby:

```
polys.each { |poly| poly.edges.each {|edge| draw edge.start, edge.end } }
```

(`polys` is an Array of Polygons, edges is a method of Polygon returning an Array of Edges)

Ideally I would like to shorten this to something like this:

```
polys.each.edges.each { draw _.start, _.end }
```

More specifically I would like to know:

- How could we write a method_missing hack as with the first each? (Upon being called with a missing method, the enumerator could call this method on each item returned from the enumeration)
- Is there a way to get rid of the `|x|` using any symbol or default name?

Comment: What you want to do is problematic in Ruby (or any scripting language) as Ruby doesn't know anything about the receiver until runtime.  Compare `[[1,2],[3,4]].each { |e| puts e }` with `[[1,2],[3,4]].each { |_,e| puts e }` How could a default value for the block variable(s) be used here?

Comment: As a C coder many moons ago, "verbose writing" brings a smile to my face. Though its no shorter, you might find it clearer to separate what you have into methods in the obvious way: `def draw_edge(edge); draw edge.start, edge.end; end; def draw_poly(poly); poly.each { |edge| draw_edge(edge) }; end; def draw_polys(polys) { |poly| draw_poly(poly) }`.

Comment: Asking for a gem that provides functionality x is off-topic so you should remove that from the question. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thanks for the remarks (commas corrected). @CarySwoveland: I am asking for a language feature that allows for a name such as x to be used if no |...| is used. Think: How would Perl do it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Closest you can do would be:

```
polys.flat_map(&:edges).each { |_| draw _.start, _.end }
```

`flat_map` will convert an array in another array and flatten it to a single dimension array. If the inside of a block is calling a single method with no parameters, you can use the `&:edges` shortcut.

This being said, I would probably keep it closer to your initial proposal, as it's more readable:

```
polys.each do |poly| 
  poly.edges.each {|edge| draw edge.start, edge.end }
end
```

Remember, you write code once but it's read a lot, so readability trumps terseness.

Comment: `polys.flat_map(&:edges).each {|edge| draw(edge.start, edge.end) }` is better, no need for both map and flatten as separate methods.

Comment: Also, if they define a `draw_edge` method they can just write `polys.flat_map(&:edges).each(&method(:draw_edge))`